# Material UI with Bootstrap not responsive

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, material-ui

am developing an app using react and material ui also using Bootstrap 4
.bootstrap is responsive but material ui components are not adjusting based on bootstrap width i.e responsive  so what should to make responsive with bootstrap 4

import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import Header from '../components/common/header/Header';

```
class HomeView extends Component {
render() {
 return (
  <MuiThemeProvider>
    <div className="container-fluid NOPDNG text-center">
      <Header showLogo={false} showLogout={false} userInfo={userInfo} showTitle={true} />
      <section id="signUpContainer">
        <Paper zDepth={1} id="Paper">
          <div className='row bo-gutters'>
            <div className="col-sm-12 text-center">
              <h5 id="signUpTitle"> Sign Up </h5>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-12 text-left">
              <TextField
                hintText="Name"
                floatingLabelText="Name"

              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-12 text-left">
              <TextField
                hintText="Email"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-12 text-left">
              <TextField
                hintText="Password"
                floatingLabelText="Password"
              />
            </div>

            <div className="col-sm-12 text-left">
              <RadioButtonGroup name="shipSpeed" defaultSelected="not_light" onChange={this.onChangeRole.bind(this)}>

                <RadioButton
                  value="demo1"
                  label="demo1"
                />
                <RadioButton
                  value="demo2"
                  label="demo2"
                />

              </RadioButtonGroup>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-12 text-left">
              <TextField
                hintText="Mobile"

              />
            </div>

            <div className="col-sm-12 text-left">
              <section className="PDNG_TP_10PX">
                <RaisedButton label="Sign Up"
                  buttonStyle={{ background: "#ac4074" }}
                  secondary={true}
                  onClick={this.onClickSignUp}
                />
              </section>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Paper>
      </section>

    </div>
    <Footer />
  </MuiThemeProvider> )}
 }
```

---

Comment: I guess material ui supports responsiveness. Please check the material ui documentation https://material-ui-next.com/layout/grid/

Comment: sorry to forget that i am suing material UI v0.20.0 http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field

Comment: Well in that case, you might be missing some styling. Please show the code snippet.

Comment: import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';                                                          
  class HomeView extends Component {  render() {

    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        < Header showLogo={true} showLogout={true} userInfo={this.props.userInfo} />
        < DocumentList />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

Comment: i couln't format my snippet

Comment: I couldn't see any responsive code been written here.

Comment: can somebody format my code i don't know how to format

Comment: I would recommend you to use 'react-bootstrap'. It would make you life easy.

Comment: how you are importing bootstrap.css ?

Comment: i have given CDN link of bootstrap 4 inside public/index.html